# How do I select by a range of starting characters?

Tags: mysql, database, select, range, startswith

Here is my mySQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `eodList` 
WHERE datechanged>='$curdate' 
GROUP BY symbolName 
ORDER BY dateChanged DESC
```

How do I get all rows (for example) where `symbolName` starts with letters `A-F`?

---

Update:

I need something that can be easily changed to another range without alot of code changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with [Regex](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

```
WHERE symbolName REGEXP '^[A-F]'
```

Answer (score 7):

Faster than `Regular expressions` and `SUBSTRING()` function calls. This will use the index of `symbolName` :

```
WHERE symbolName >= 'A' 
  AND symbolName < 'G'
```

There is an issue with the case sensitivity though. Do you want names which start with `a..f` too or not?

If you want only names that start with uppercase and the table has `utf8` character set, use:

```
WHERE symbolName >= 'A' COLLATE utf8_bin
  AND symbolName < 'G' COLLATE utf8_bin
```

For other character sets, use the corresponding `_bin` collation.

Comment: I know this post is a few years old, but is there a way to run this and include the 2nd char. I tried using <= 'G' but that won't do it

Comment: @Helto what do you mean with "2nd char"?

Comment: Yes I didn't get it at first, but I see now that I can just use < 'GZ' or < 'GZZ' to get what I need.

By "2nd char" I meant the second character being compared, in this case the 'G'

Comment: If you want the words that start with G included, why not use `< 'H'`? (or some of the suggestions in the other answers)

Comment: It needs to be dynamic, I didn't want to use an alphabet array to pick the next letter, and it wouldn't work for 'Z'. Thanks for your reponse, I got it working :)

Comment: @Helto I guess you could use `WHERE symbolName >= 'A' AND symbolName < CHAR(1+ASCII('F'))` but I don't have time to check right now (and I'm sure that would have to be adjusted if you use utf8.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `eodList` 
WHERE datechanged>='$curdate' AND


((SUBSTRING(symbolName, 1, 1) >= "A" AND SUBSTRING(symbolName, 1, 1) <="F"))
GROUP BY symbolName 
ORDER BY dateChanged DESC
```

Comment: What do you mean with that @sll ?

Comment: couldn't you just replace those conditions with `(SUBSTRING(symbolName, 1, 1) >= "A" AND SUBSTRING(symbolName, 1, 1) <="F")`?

Comment: @genesis: I wondering whether an approach proposed by you is faster/slower than approach using built in REGEX

Comment: aha. I'm not sure, I'll maybe try it through